# I have a secret that I have kept hidden from my circle of friends and family

Tags: sentence-structure, participles, participial-adjectives

When I was browsing internet. I saw this sentence. I have a doubt on the usage of 
"have kept hidden"
What tense is it?
Is it Active voice of present perfect? If so why there is a word "hidden" which is the past participle form of hide?

Is it passive voice of present perfect? If so, why they are using "kept" instead of been?

Comment: So, what is the definition of "kept"?  And what do you find if you Google `define hidden`?

Comment: @HotLicks  secret

Comment: And what part of speech?

Comment: It’s in the present tense; had it been in the past tense, it would have read *had* not *have*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think OP's confusion arises from the proximity of the two participles, "kept" and "hidden".

The sentence:

> I have a secret that I have kept hidden from my circle of friends and family.

comes from combining these two sentences:

*I have a secret.* + *I have kept the secret hidden from my circle of friends and family.*

The structure "that I have kept hidden..." is therefore a relative clause where "that" refers back to "a secret". "have kept" is a verb in the present perfect tense and in the active form. "hidden" is a past participle that **does not form part of the verb phrase "have kept"** but is used as an adjective that refers to the object "secret". We call "hidden" an **object complement**. Proof that "hidden" is not verbal (passive) but adjectival is that we can replace it with an adjective:

> I have a secret that I have kept confidential.

Comment: In fact, Merriam-Webster defines "hidden" as an adjective.

Comment: @HotLicks Actually, "hidden" can be the past participle of the verb "hide" (in perfect tenses: *They have hidden the treasure* and in the passive voice: *The treasure was hidden by the pirates*) or an adjective, as in OP's sentence.